# PDO how do I set a datetime value to NULL in a prepared statement?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm getting an error trying to clear the value of a datetime field using PDO. The problem is the NULL value being passed as a string is being quoted by the prepare statement and SQL then returns a error

```
Example:
//Test Values
$_POST['FromDate'] = 'NULL';
$_POST['ToDate'] = '20140905';

//Update statement
$SQLQuery = "UPDATE A
             SET
             FromDate = :FromDate
             ,ToDate = :ToDate
             FROM dbo.TEST AS A 
            WHERE
                        ID = 1 ";

//User Params
$UserParams = array(':FromDate' => $_POST['FromDate']
                   ,':ToDate' => $_POST['ToDate']
                   );

//Run the query
$s = $handler->prepare($SQLQuery);
$s->execute(array($UserParams));
```

The SQL query then returns an error as 'NULL' is a string and the FromDate is DATETIME. It needs to be NULL not 'NULL'

```
    UPDATE A
    SET
    FromDate = 'NULL'
    etc...
```

Comment: Probably because you're passing it the string `'NULL'` instead of the value `NULL`.

Comment: _You_ made it a string. `'NULL'` is a string containing the word, `NULL` is the constant. Change `$_POST['FromDate'] = 'NULL';` to `$_POST['FromDate'] = NULL;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to manually set it to `NULL` then don't mess with the post variable.

Just hardcode it as a PHP null object (of course not a string `'NULL'`)

```
$stmt = $handler->prepare($SQLQuery);
$success = $stmt->execute(array(':FromDate' => NULL,
                                ':ToDate' => $_POST['ToDate']
));
if($success) {
   echo 'updated!';
} else {
   echo 'failed';
}
```